# Are there no planar dragons in the Peaceable Kingdoms of Arcadia?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, dragons

I've been doing a bit of reading, and I discovered that there are planar dragons for pretty much every Outer Plane of the Wheel... except for Arcadia. I recall reading some long time ago that they don't like dragons over there because of some war that a god who lives there fought in, and as such dragons are not welcome in Arcadia. But I don't recall the source for this, so I can't go back to check this. So my question is:

**Is there a kind of planar dragon who lives in the Peacable Kingdoms of Arcadia?**

Comment: Which edition and campaign setting are you asking about? The planes can vary a fair bit.

Comment: 3.5e. But is this different in other editions?

Comment: Very. In fourth edition, Arcadia doesn't exist as its own plane, and many, many monsters are different. In second edition, planar dragons were generally only mentioned rarely and in supplements or adventures that were campaign setting-specific, and the Planescape setting specifically stated that dragons were rare outside the Prime at one point. I take it from your context that you're using the Greyhawk campaign setting's version of the Great Wheel cosmology?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I know that Arcadia isn't around in 4e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research into this cause I did not understand your question at first as dragons can be found in any plane but are only native to the Prime plane other then Gem Dragons, Force Dragons and Prism' Dragons. So to answer your question I have to first state that the Question I am answering is their Dragons who live in Arcadia the Answer is yes.

Emerald Dragons and Sapphire Dragons and obviously Force Dragons and Prism Dragons.
Radiant Dragons from the Draconomicon.
Any Metallic Dragon of Lawful Alignment could be found there realistically.

As is their a Specific Planar dragon that was native to Arcadia, Not OUT SIDE DRAGON MAG's their is another out planar realm that is host to dragon gods an their servants but Arcadia is for humanoid gods and their like. The Dragon Peaceful(if you can call a dragon realm peaceful) realm is called the Dragon Eyrie from the Players Guide to Faerun.

But Dragon Magazine #321 Has a few; The Adamantine Dragon from Bytopia, the Arboreal Dragon from Avendor, the Axial Dragon from Mechanus, the Beast Dragon from the Beastlands and the Concordant Dragon from the distant outlands.